# Image and text in contact bar

Tags: html, css

Okay so the desired outcome of this is to have the images on the left and the text sit to the right of the images, screenshot below:

```css
.contact_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #2c3e50;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #c9c9c9;
}

.contact_bar_container {
    width: 1050px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.contact_bar_text {
    width: 100%;
}

.contact_bar_call {
    background-image: url(/images/call.png);
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 8px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.contact_bar_email {
    background-image: url(/images/email.png);
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact_bar">
  <div class="contact_bar_container">
  
    <div class="contact_bar_call">
      <div class="contact_bar_text">
        Call here
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contact_bar_email">
      <div class="contact_bar_text">
        Email here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the image to be left of the text and automatically understand when the first line of text (phone number) is finished it will then have the email image with a 5px margin and then the email image and address.

Comment: make use of padding-left .contact_bar_email and .contact_bar_call

Comment: You can add `background-repeat: no-repeat` if you don't want the image to be duplicated. But maybe you can use an img html tag instead of a background-image, it will be more easier

Comment: use background-position:left and background-repeat:no-repeat;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution using img html tag instead of background-image. I edited a bit your html code.

So you just have use a `<img src="###" />`tag instead of the `<div class="contact_image"></div>`

```css
.contact_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #2c3e50;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #c9c9c9;
}

.contact_bar_container {
    width: 1050px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.contact_bar_content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
  }

.contact_image{
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="contact_bar">
  <div class="contact_bar_container">
  
    <div class="contact_bar_content">
      <div class="contact_image">
      </div>
      <div class="contact_bar_text">
        Call here
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contact_bar_content">
      <div class="contact_image">
      </div>
      <div class="contact_bar_text">
        Email here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```